# Jquery click-drop menu not working for me?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to implement a Jquery Javascript menu onto a webpage.

Jquery code:

```
 $(".navigation ul ul, .shoppingbasket ul ul").css({display: "none"});
$(".navigation ul li, .shoppingbasket ul li").click(function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').slideToggle(400);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><h3>View Fruit List</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Apple</li>
            <li>Lemon</li>
            <li>Banana</li>
            <li>Avocado</li>                
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><h3>View Car List</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Pinto</li>
            <li>Lemon</li>
            <li>Mercedes</li>
            <li>Nova</li>                
        </ul>
    </li>        
</ul>
```

[The code works on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssEb5/5/), but doesn't work [on my site](http://meow.screengazer.net/testing) (you can view my source code to see what I did). I have linked jquery.js and put the plugin on the page. Would I need to link any other files--am I missing something? What do I need to do to get this code to work successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // your jQuery code
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/